# Find difference between datetime and time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datetime variable

```
2017-03-10 13:05:00.000
```

and a time variable

```
12:00:00.0000000
```

I need to find the difference between the datetime and the time on the datetime's date so I get 1 hour and 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select datediff( minute, cast('2017-03-10 13:05:00.000' as time)
 ,  cast ('12:00:00.0000000' as time))

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @D datetime = '2017-03-10 13:05:00.000'
Declare @T time     = '12:00:00.0000000'

Select AsMinutes = DateDiff(MINUTE,@T,cast(@D as time))
      ,AsTime    = Format(DateAdd(MINUTE,DateDiff(MINUTE,@T,cast(@D as time)),0),'HH:mm')
      ,AsString  = replace(Format(DateAdd(MINUTE,DateDiff(MINUTE,@T,cast(@D as time)),0),'H x1 m')+' minutes','x1','hour')
```

Returns

```
AsMinutes   AsTime  AsString
65          01:05   1 hour 5 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . .

```
select dateadd(millisecond,
               datediff(millisecond, cast(datetimevar as time), timevar)
               0)
```

You probably want to cast the result back to a time data type.